# Could not read entity state from ResultSet NumberFormatException: For input string

Tags: java, hibernate, enumeration

Ok, so this is not a real question, as I have already figured out what went wrong here.  I'll post this question anyways to help future googles.

I was getting a strange exception while accessing my entity class's attribute field that is declared as a custom enum type.

```
public enum OrderMetaDataAttribute {

    PARTY_ID("partyId"),
    PARTY_NAME("partyName"),
    [...] 
}
```

---

```
@Table
public class OrderMetaData extends AbstractPersistentObject {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private OrderMetaDataAttribute attribute;
   
    [...]
}
```

---

SQL:

```
insert into order_meta_data (id, attribute, value, order_id) values
('11', 'PARTY_ID', '0815', '1'),
('12', 'PARTY_NAME', 'testParty', '1'),
```

---

The stacktrace looked something like this:

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[org.exmaple.order.model.OrderMetaData#11]
    [...]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Datenumwandlungsfehler beim Umwandeln von "partyId"
Data conversion error converting "partyId" [22018-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:457)
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "partyId"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertToInt(Value.java:982)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:806)
    ... 107 more
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here was, that I was missing a

> @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)

annotation on my entity's attribute.  I assume this has caused hibernate to interpret the enumeration as an intege rather than a string.

```
@Table
public class OrderMetaData extends AbstractPersistentObject {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderMetaDataAttribute attribute;
}
```

Comment: Thank god I saw your comment at least now, after spending a couple of hours on a similar issue ;)